# Specifically for JS, CSS, HTML: what is the difference between optimization, compression, minification, tidying, concatenation?

Tags: javascript, performance, html, css, apache

When we talk about source code and the file which contains the code like CSS, HTML, JavaScript and we also talk about performance of a web site or application, what is the differences between these terms?

- Optimization
- Compression
- Minification
- Tidying
- Concatenation

Answer (score 12):

- Optimization - general term meaning any of the following:
- Compression - fewer bytes through algorithmic means
- Minification - fewer bytes by using shorter syntax with the same meaning
- Tidying - removing code that doesn't do anything and removing redundant code
- Concatenation - delivering all the data in one request rather than multiple requests

Comment: +1 Thanks can you give a simple example of each using a simple css code?

Comment: Is Minification the same alpha conversion? (lambda calculus). Also code that doesnt do anything is also known as "dead code"

Comment: @Raynos: 'DeadCode' is covered under Tidying. Minification would be replacing `while(true)` with `for(;;)` (both loop forever but the second one is 4 bytes shorter).

Comment: @Jitendra:  Compression - gzipped.  Minification - code rewritten to be less characters but still work.  Internal variables might be changed from "theXYCoordinate" to just "a". Tidying - can't get simpler than what Scott said.  Concatenation - you might combine jquery, jquery ui, and your own JS all into one file.  It's all the same code but 1 HTTP Request instead of 3.

Comment: @Andy - +1 How to do these things with any website I develop.

Comment: @Jitendra, I've used this one before with success.  It's pretty easy to use it in a build task or standalone.  http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxminquickstart.ashx